# SyntaxError: The requested module '@socket.io/component-emitter' does not provide an export named 'Emitter'

Tags: socket.io, next.js

I've use socket.io, after upgrading next.js from 10 to 12 I'll got this error!

```
SyntaxError: The requested module '@socket.io/component-emitter' does not provide an export named 'Emitter
```

This is how I've import socket.io

```js
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
```

Comment: I found it's because I was update `socket.io-client` package to 4.4.1 version. when I downgrade package to 4.2.0, everything was fixed.

Comment: You should post this as an answer.